# System.out.println in Hadoop Driver Class

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to measure time to Hadoop job to execute. In my Driver class I have:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end-start);
```

But where does hadoop send the System.out.println()?

**EDIT**

When the program ends the terminal prints out Job Counters, can I get the total execution time as:

`Total execution time = Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots + Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots + Total time spent by all maps task + Total time spent by all reduces task` ?

Comment: You should put the computation code in between `start` and `end`. By the way, currentTimeMillis is not a reliable way of benchmarking, use jmh.

Comment: I put the computation code in my program, but I don't understand where the System.out.println() goes  in hadoop

Comment: Check in the logs.

Comment: @jjrjrjjjr SOP will send data to a standard output stream if it's not changed and check logs also.

Comment: in my hadoop/logs/userlogs/job I have different container folders, each of these has stdout file but it is empty

Comment: why did you delete your Spark question from yesterday? This is not how Stackoverflow works ...

Comment: @UninformedUser Ah sorry I am new to the community, anyway because there were no answers and I was able to solve in my own..

Comment: the common practice is to provide the answer then, even if you did it by yourself. Imagine everybody deleting their thread once the answer was found. How could others find those answers when having the same or similar question? That"S the whole idea of archiving question + solution ...

Comment: I am sorry, so I hope that someone will answer to this question in order to be helpful to everybody!